# How to automatically move files across network computers when they are both on & ready?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is the best application to Sync two folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/13493/which-is-the-best-application-to-sync-two-folders)

On my network I have two Windows machines. One is a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, the other is my personal PC, a Windows 7 x64 machine.

I need a way to automatically *move* files from the server (2008 R2) to the user machine (Windows 7) whenever both PCs are on and ready. To do this, I would have a share drive available on the user machine that the server can copy files to if needed.

I could use a script for this, but I prefer not to do that if there exists a solution to this already.

I could use Windows Live Mesh for this, but Live Mesh does a *copy* between the two PCs. What I expect is that the copy on the server machine is deleted once it has been successfully transfered to the user machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I now realize you requested 'moving' files specifically.  Which isn't synchronizing, and I don't think I've run into a Sync util that actually 'moves' files, or which actively detects computer 'readiness'. I'd reverse my vote to close but it's stuck now.